# React native video as GL texture

Tags: react-native, webgl, expo

It seems it’s not possible to use a video as a texture with **expo-gl** (texImage2D is not able to take any video params, cf. [context definition](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-gl/src/WebGL2RenderingContext.ts#L428) and [API documentation](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/sdk/gl-view.md#webgl-api)). This feature is currently [requested on the canny](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/expo-gl-video-support).

I'm looking to convert an **expo-av** video to an ArrayBuffer with pixel data or any way to pass a video as a texture to a shader.

I made some research but I didn't find any solution for the moment:

- gl-react: video processing: https://github.com/gre/gl-react/issues/215
- react-native-gpuimage (react-native-video is not working inside GL.Node): https://github.com/CubeSugar/react-native-GPUImage/issues/1

Actually, this could be interesting: https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing. This library purpose is to edit, trim and compress videos, but there's actually no way to pass custom shaders.

A lot of issues has been open on Github (even on the expo org [expo-three](https://github.com/expo/expo-three/issues/3) package) but there's no answer yet. I'm looking for resources or any advice to accomplish this. For the moment, the best solution I can see is to do a sprite sheet.

Comment: @nick bolas,  I have zero experience with react native but is webgl a thing in react native? I thought the "native" part of react native is that you interact with native APIs like Metal, Vulkan, OpenGL not WebGL

Comment: Yep, expo did an OpenGL implementation of the WebGL API but they did’t implement videos textures so I’m looking for an alternative

Comment: what platform??

Comment: Both, iOS and Android (not web)